# how to solve mqdc.dll error in IBM MQ connection

Tags: ibm-mq

I have installed IBM MQ client into my local machine version 9.0.0.0 . Now I wrote 
a windows service to connect to remote IBM MQ but I am getting error like

Unable to load DLL 'C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin\mqdc.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

And I found this link for sollution but I dont understand a word
Please explain and help me regarding this . Please help . I am clueless here

**sollution link**

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC90595

Comment: Are you able to locate this dll at the path in error ?

Comment: Try making it the primary install: `setmqinst -n Installation1 -i`

Comment: Can you confirm if you see the file `C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin\mqdc.dll`?  This a MQ client dll and as the technote you referenced refers to will only be present if the MQ client component was installed on a "server".  Since you said you installed MQ client it should be in place and the primary install may be the issue.

Comment: @JoshMc thanks for reply :) . but I don't have this C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin\mqdc.dll in my local machine . you are saying to solve this issue I have to install client component into server ? so if I install server mq also into my machine then will it be ok? and please explain the primary installation setmqinst -n Installation1 -i ... I dont understand what i have to do

Comment: @Prany thanks for reply :) . but i dont have this dll into my local machine .. I just installed mq client version 9.0.0.0 ... instaed i have amqmdnet.dll which is used in managed mode and .mqdc.dll is used unmanaged mode means client type.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I just installed mq client version 9.0.0.0"?  If you installed mq client v9.0.0.0 you would have `mqdc.dll`.  If all you have is `amqmdnet.dll` it seems you did not install the MQ client and only the MQ's .NET dll file from NuGet or some such, if that is all you want then you would need to specify Manged mode.  If you use Unmanaged mode which is the default it requires the full MQ client install, if you want this Google "MQC9" and get either the full client package `9.0.0.4-IBM-MQC-Win64`  or the redistributable client package `9.0.0.4-IBM-MQC-Redist-Win64`.

Comment: The full client package installs as a you would a normal windows program (ex: `setup.exe`), the redistributable comes as a zip file that you can just extract and ensure the proper bin directory is in your PATH.

Comment: @JoshMc I guess I installed the redistributable client package 9.0.0.4-IBM-MQC-Redist-Win64 . thanks again josh for pointing out my errors . many many thanks :D

Comment: @JoshMc yes you are right . I checked I installed the redistributable client package 9.0.0.4-IBM-MQC-Redist-Win64. I am going to uninstall it and reinstall full client package .

Comment: The redistributable is fine, you just need to get a later version such as 9.0.0.4.  I believe the issue you are facing is is [APAR IT17812](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg1IT17812) which was fixed at 9.0.0.1.

Comment: If you have 9.0.0.4 then it should not be a problem, can you make sure the version of `amqmdnet.dll` you are using with your application matches the version of the redistributable client you installed, you can find the version by right clicking the dll.

Comment: Make sure you follow recommendations "[here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q123550_.html)" if you want to use redistributable.  Also note as I said before if you specify Managed mode you only need the `amqmdnet.dll` file.  Any reason you want to use Unmanaged over Manged mode?

Comment: @JoshMc I checked the version its 9.0.0.0 version redistributable. unmanaged mode is default that's why im using this . I dont know how to change it into managed mode . I can connect to my remote mq using ibm mq explorer and in property it says connection type is client .

Comment: Get 9.0.0.4 redist and it should work fine in unmanaged mode.   How you switch to managed mide is by specifying it in your properties.

Comment: Get 9.0.0.4 redist and it should work fine in unmanaged mode. How you switch to managed mode is by specifying it in your properties hash table that you pass in your program.  In the other similar question you asked @subbaraoc already explained and pointed you to an example of how to set it to Managed Mode.  You really should not ask the same question twice.

Comment: saha.jan, did you get things working with the Redist client?  As I said you just need to go to a newer version no need to do a full install.

Comment: @JoshMc yes I can connect to remote MQ using version 9.0.0.4 redist . thank you :D for the sollution . version 9.0.0.4 redist has mqdc.dll and all the dll files which are required to connect to remote MQ . thank you sooooooooo much :D :D

Comment: @JoshMc can you put your suggesion into answer . So that I can validate it and anyone will get the idea how to solve it.